# How to setup network bridge in KDE Plasma?

Tags: networking, kubuntu, kde, 22.10

I want to use a specific NIC as a slave for my bridge network (in this case, my WiFI).  How do I do that on Plasma?

Wish the network manager had like a quick help for something like that.  When I tried it without trying to specify a NIC, it won't even let me connect, and same went if I tried to add my ethernet:

[image]
[image]

And while I can use Netplan, which I ended up doing, I'd like to know how to do it from the GUI for the people who aren't comfortable with the terminal.

I mimicked the same "GUI look" from the Netplan bridge and the one I created with the GUI and no dice on that front.

This is the config I did for my desktop at work (no access to the GUI since I'm home):
[image]